# Facebook share link is not showing image within the post?(get parameter in url)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I have added this code in head part

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="your_image_here" />
```

Case 1: 
When i click share link. with below url it working properly.
Example: www.exampledomainname.com/test it fetching with image

In second case

Adding get parameter with url

```
Example: www.exampledomainname.com/test?username="AAA";
```

Because every time username will change.

```
 <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=www.exampledomainname.com/test?username=AAA" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-social btn-facebook"><span class="icon icon-facebook"></span> Share on Facebook</button></a 

$input = "www.exampledomainname.com/test?username=AAA";
$encoded = urlencode($input)
 <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u='.$encoded.'" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-social btn-facebook"><span class="icon icon-facebook"></span> Share on Facebook</button></a
```

I have tried this url (www.exampledomainname.com/test?username="AAA"")with Facebook debugger tool also. it not fetching  image.
How to fetch the image in preview during sharing.

Comment: `og:image` must be an absolute url... and the `u` parameter value must be urlencoded

Comment: yes  pipe, i am using url encoded and sending, go:image is in absolute path only.

Comment: Based on your code, you are not urlencoding the parameter... you cannot have `www.exampledomainname.com/test?username="AAA"`(double-quotes) in the url... Are you sure the username es `"AAA"` or is it `AAA` ? If the later is correct, then the url must be `www.exampledomainname.com/test?username=AAA` without double quotes

Comment: yes pipe, i have tried with and without quotes both are not fetching images. url encoding i am using.

Comment: Facebook has a "cache"... But you can force a refresh trying your url here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: _“How to fetch the image in preview during sharing”_ - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30166148/1427878